# Control difference between Hide() and Visible?

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

I was wondering about the difference between using a Control’s `Hide()` method compared to setting the `Visible` property to false.

When would I want to use the one over the other?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

They are equivalent.  From the documentation for [Control.Hide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.hide.aspx):

> Hiding the control is equivalent to
>   setting the Visible property to false.

You can confirm this with reflector:

```
public void Hide()
{
    this.Visible = false;
}
```

You might use Show() or Hide() when you know the value and use Visible when you take the visibility in as a parameter, although personally I would always use Visible.

Comment: Yes, this can be confirmed from the `System.Windows.Forms.Control.Hide()` [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,0ed3da8c7abbae2a,references).

Answer (score 5):

Use whatever you like, `Hide()` or `Visible`, but I can't find any reason to prefer one of them except if you are trying to check the control visibility status, so you should say `if(pic.Visible)` and in this case you can't use the method `Hide()` you should use the property `Visible`

Comment: It seems when you call `Hide()` on a control the `Visible` property is set to `False`.

Comment: @Mary this makes sense

Answer (score 0):

It is really more about your preference here. The two methods will achieve the same result in the same way.

I prefer calling methods, which say what they're doing to change the state of objects. Some people prefer setting the properties of an object.