# I cant dispose the first form when calling second form using c#

Tags: c#

how can i dispose the first form when calling second form using c#, Here is my code, :

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2();
f2.Show();
this.Dispose();
```

Comment: y u try to dispose the first form , u should hide the form. because it is a parent form

Comment: Sorry sir im new in programming so i not really familiar with parent form.

Comment: So what do you really want to happen? Do you want the Parent Form to hide?

Comment: See my two form project : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975508/reach-control-from-another-page-asp-net

Comment: Thank you sir someone below already explained it :) thanks for kindness. I know now why it's not working

Answer (score 1):

When you run the command `new Form2()` you are creating a new Form instance from `Form1` as a child element. Therefore, you cannot dispose the parent, `Form1` (which is `this` in your code).

Comment: Thanks for this knowledge sir. Now i understand why it's not working

Comment: This is not really true. `f2` is not a child of `this`... The main "problem" here is that `Form1` is the MainForm of the Application: `Application.Run(new Form1());` that's why `Application` (well in fact it's `ApplicationContext`) handles the `HandleDestroyed` event of this instance of `Form1` and calls `ExitThread`which causes the application to shut down. *That means closing/disposing the main form of an application will cause closing the whole application.*

Comment: Thank you sir stephan for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Application will close if you dispose the main form.

Try this code

```
this.Visible = false;

Form2 f2 = new Form2();

f2.ShowDialog();

this.Visible = true;
```

This will just hide the main form as long as Form2 is open.

Comment: Wouldm't this.hide() into making visiblity true for the new form, Then if you need to come back just call another new form? Or would that cause a problem.

Comment: Thank you sir Zaid Al Shattle that's the explanation i wanted to read. First i thought visible and hide has the same effect. I thought this.Hide will create another form but since it was hidden im not going to see that i already created multiple form in background. So now i get it that i should use this.Hide to avoid creating multiple form1 or parent form. Is my understanding is right ?

Comment: Zaid, Hiding the control is equivalent to setting the Visible property to false. Follow [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3600354/control-difference-between-hide-and-visible)

Answer (score 0):

Why you are trying to dispose the main form, Instead You can simply hide the first form:

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2();

f2.Show();   //It shows the new form(Second Form)

this.Hide(); //It hides the current form
```

It will hide the Main form and shows the Second form.